# i keep getting increased repetitive onChange passes on my observables with database changes

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I have a Dictionary app where I want to assign existing synonyms to a word in the dictionary.  To accomplish this I am using  is using a M:N relationship between the word and synonym tables.

Entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table",
indices = @Index(value = "word", unique = true))
public class Word {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String word;

    @Ignore
    public Word(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public Word(long id, String word) {
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
}

@Entity(tableName = "synonym_table")
public class Synonym {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long sid;
    private String synonym;

    @Ignore
    public Synonym(String synonym) {
        this.synonym = synonym;
    }

    public Synonym(long sid, String synonym) {
        this.sid = sid;
        this.synonym = synonym;
    }

    public long getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public void setSid(long id) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    public String getSynonym() {
        return synonym;
    }

    public void setSynonym(String synonym) {
        this.synonym = synonym;
    }
}

@Entity(tableName = "word_synonym_join_table",
primaryKeys= {"word_id" , "synonym_id"},
foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = Word.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "word_id"),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Synonym.class, parentColumns = "sid", childColumns = "synonym_id")})
public class WordSynonymJoin {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "word_id")
    private long wordId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "synonym_id")
    private long synonymId;

    public WordSynonymJoin(long wordId, long synonymId) {
        this.wordId = wordId;
        this.synonymId = synonymId;
    }

    public long getWordId() {
        return wordId;
    }

    public void setWordId(long wordId) {
        this.wordId = wordId;
    }

    public long getSynonymId() {
        return synonymId;
    }

    public void setSynonymId(long synonymId) {
        this.synonymId = synonymId;
    }
}
```

To retrieve the data for the Word and associated Synonyms, I created a POJO called WordWithSynonyms.

```
public class WordWithSynonyms {
    @Embedded
    public Word word;

    @Embedded
    public WordSynonymJoin wordSynonymJoin;
}
```

The Daos are as follows:

```
@Dao
public interface WordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table")
    public LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE id =:wordId")
    public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordById(long wordId);

    @Query("SELECT * from word_table WHERE word =:value")
    public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordByValue(String value);

    @Insert
    public long insert(Word word);

    @Delete
    public void delete(Word word);

    @Update
    public void update(Word word);

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
    public void deleteAll();
}

@Dao
public interface SynonymDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM synonym_table")
    public LiveData<List<Synonym>> getAllSynonyms();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM synonym_table WHERE synonym =:value")
    public LiveData<List<Synonym>> getSynonymByValue(String value);

    @Insert
    public void insert(Synonym synonym);

    @Delete
    public void delete(Synonym synonym);

    @Query("DELETE FROM synonym_table")
    public void deleteAll();
}

@Dao
public interface WordSynonymJoinDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table INNER JOIN word_synonym_join_table " +
            "ON word_table.id = word_synonym_join_table.word_id " +
            "WHERE word_synonym_join_table.synonym_id =:synonymId")
    public LiveData<List<WordWithSynonyms>> getWordsBySynonym(long synonymId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM synonym_table INNER JOIN word_synonym_join_table " +
            "ON synonym_table.sid = word_synonym_join_table.synonym_id " +
            "WHERE word_synonym_join_table.word_id =:wordId")
    public LiveData<List<SynonymWithWords>> getSynonymsByWord(long wordId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM synonym_table INNER JOIN word_synonym_join_table " +
            "ON synonym_table.sid = word_synonym_join_table.synonym_id " +
            "WHERE word_synonym_join_table.word_id !=:wordId")
    public LiveData<List<SynonymWithWords>> getSynonymsByNotWord(long wordId);

    @Insert
    public void insert(WordSynonymJoin wordSynonymJoin);

    @Delete
    public void delete(WordSynonymJoin wordSynonymJoin);

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_synonym_join_table")
    public void deleteAll();
}
```

When I arrive on the Synonyms Activity, i pass the wordId to retrieve the current synonyms for that word through a ViewModel observer.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_synonym);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    wordId = Long.parseLong(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_WORD_ID));

    //SynonymViewModel synonymViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SynonymViewModel.class);
    WordSynonymJoinViewModel wordSynonymJoinViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordSynonymJoinViewModel.class);

    //synonymAdapter = new SynonymListAdapter(this);
    synonymAdapter = new SynonymWithWordListAdapter(this);
    synonynRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_syonym);

    if (wordId != 0) {
        wordSynonymJoinViewModel.getSynonymsByWord(wordId).observe(SynonymActivity.this, new Observer<List<SynonymWithWords>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<SynonymWithWords> synonymWithWords) {
                synonymAdapter.setSynonyms(synonymWithWords);
                synonymAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    synonynRecyclerView.setAdapter(synonymAdapter);
    synonynRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SynonymActivity.this));

}
```

I then give the user the opportunity to associate an existing, unassigned synonym from the Synonym table to the Word table.

I retrieve the unused and available Synonyms through a separate ViewModel observer inside of an AlertDialog which uses a spinner to display them via the WordSynonymJoin table using another ViewModel observer.
Finally, inside of that ViewModel observer when the user clicks the OK button on the AlertDialog, a third VieModel observer is ran to do the actual insertion into the WordSynonymJoin table.

```
case R.id.synonym_assign_synonym:
    final WordSynonymJoinViewModel wordSynonymJoinViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(SynonymActivity.this).get(WordSynonymJoinViewModel.class);
    wordSynonymJoinViewModel.getSynonymsByNotWord(wordId).observe(SynonymActivity.this, new Observer<List<SynonymWithWords>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<SynonymWithWords> synonymWithWords) {

            List<String> synonymsNotAssignList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (SynonymWithWords sww : synonymWithWords)
                synonymsNotAssignList.add(sww.synonym.getSynonym());

            AlertDialog.Builder assignSynonymDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SynonymActivity.this);
            assignSynonymDialog.setTitle("Select New Category:");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_spinner_view, null);

            final Spinner synonymSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.alert_dialog_spinner);

            final SynonymViewModel synonymViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(SynonymActivity.this).get(SynonymViewModel.class);

            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(SynonymActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, synonymsNotAssignList);
            spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            synonymSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

            synonymSpinner.setSelection(synonymId);

            assignSynonymDialog.setView(view);
            assignSynonymDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    final String synonymValue = synonymSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    // get new synonym id
                    synonymViewModel.getSynonymByValue(synonymValue).observe(SynonymActivity.this, new Observer<List<Synonym>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Synonym> synonyms) {
                            long id = 0;


                            if (!synonyms.get(0).getSynonym().equals(synonymValue)) {
                                if (synonyms.size() > 1)
                                    Toast.makeText(SynonymActivity.this, "Query found " + synonyms.size() + " which is more than the one expected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                id = synonyms.get(0).getSid();
                            }
                            WordSynonymJoinViewModel wordSynonymJoinViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(SynonymActivity.this).get(WordSynonymJoinViewModel.class);
                            wordSynonymJoinViewModel.insert(new WordSynonymJoin(wordId, id));
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
            assignSynonymDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            assignSynonymDialog.create();
            assignSynonymDialog.show();
        }
    });

    return true;
```

On the first pass, all seems to work well.  However, on successive passes where the user continues to add new synonyms to the word, it takes that many clicks on the cancel button of the AlertDialog to exit after each synonym added.  2 synonyms added, 2 click on the cancel to get back to main Activity.  3 synonyms added, 3 clicks on the cancel to remove the AlertDialog.

I am very new to this whole concept of MVVM and Room persistence so I know there will be issues.  Here is the code for the AlertDialog for adding existing, unassigned synonyms to the current word.

I don't like how much code is being used for this, but i have not been able to word my searches so that I can find ways around it.

My questions are:

Why is the code cycling +1 every time I enter associate new synonym to the word?  Am I suppose to be clearing something out.

Is this coding even remotely right?

This seems like an awful lot of work to accomplish something so seemingly small.  I think I have missed something.  Have I made this abnormally complicated?

What am I missing that this code looks so cumbersome and unwieldy?

It seems a very cumbersome way to retrieve values and I don't really think i need to observe every query that I ran above.  Maybe I am wrong.

Is there a direction of study that will help me understand this better?

Could this be where the Rx Java comes in?

I can certainly provide more code as needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that's a lot of code! :-) normally I'm telling ppl to post more not less haha, hopefully writing it out has helped you with your own problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRDL: Don't call `.observe` outside of [ON_CREATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.Event.html#ON_CREATE) state.

---

You made a `LiveData` mistake... but you are not alone! That mistake is the most common `LiveData` mistake on StackOverflow: calling `.observe` outside of `Activity#onCreate()`. This includes calling `.observe` in a click listener, on `onResume`, broadcast receiver, etc.

The problem I see in most people who uses `LivedData` for the first time is that they treat `LiveData` just like a call back, when they are not. `LiveData` is a stream. `LiveData` does not notify just one time. The `Observers` attached to the `LiveData` will continue to be notified until they are unsubscribed. Also, It is meant to be subscribed at the beginning of the life-cycle, (e.g. Activity#onCreate or Fragment#onViewCreated) and unsubscribed at the end of the life-cycle. `LiveData` automatically handles the unsubscription part, so all you need to make sure is to subscribe in `onCreate`.

The fundamental reason you are keep getting +1 Dialog is that the previous observer is not dead and you are keep adding a new subscription to the database each time you repeat the same thing. Try rotating the phone and see if the number of dialog resets back to 1. That's because all of the previous observers are unsubscribed when you rotate the screen and activity is recreated.

Maybe you could call `isShowing()` and see if any dialog is open, as suggested in another answer. However, doing so is just a work around. What if it was a `Toast` or something else that you can't check? Besides, you are lucky that you could easily spot this bug. You might be having this duplicate observer bug some place else that is not visually noticeable.

---

So I think you already know how to use `LiveData`, but it is just that you need to know how to implement reactive pattern correctly. It would be too much to explain in one writing but let me give you a simple example:

Lets say you have a button that when you press, you fetch some data from DB. In a callback-like design you often call some function in ViewModel and pass a callback instance. For example you have this:

```
//ViewModel
void getSynonymsByNotWord(WordSynonymJoin word, Callback callback) { ... }

//Activity
void onClick(View v) {
    wordSynonymJoinViewModel.changeCurrentSysnonymsByNotWord(wordId, callback);
}
```

You perform an action to ViewModel and you receive the response through callback. This is perfectly fine for callback. However, you can't do the same with `LiveData`. When using `LiveData`, View layer don't expect that there will be a response for each of the action. Instead, View layer should always blindly listen to the response, even before the button is clicked.

```
//ViewModel
private MutableLiveData wordQuery;
private Livedata synonymsByNotWord = Transformations.switchMap(wordQuery, word -> {
        return repository.getSynonymsByWord(word);
    });

LiveData getCurrentSynonymsByNotWord() {
    return synonymsByNotWord;
}

void changeCurrentSynonymsByNotWord(WordSynonymJoin word) {
    wordQuery.postValue(word);
}


//Activity
void onCreate() {
    wordSynonymJoinViewModel.getCurrentSynonymsByNotWord().observe(...);
} 

void onClick(View v) {
    wordSynonymJoinViewModel.changeCurrentSynonymsByNotWord(wordId);
}
```

And also it is okay to, but you normally don't get ViewModel from `ViewModelProviders` every time you need a view model. You should just get one view model at `onCreate`, save it as an activity instance variable, and use the same instance in the rest of the activity.

Comment: So, then, the ViewModel's changeCurrentSynonymsByNotWord( WordSynonymJoin word) method would contain the query call to the Repository instead of calling it in the UI through the ViewModel object?  I have not seen any example create a separate method.  Or is the method "changeCurrentSynonyms..." just a placeholder for the method I am using in my code to call the Repository to retrieve the row(s) from the database?  Maybe, I am missing something in the example...

Comment: I have added some more realistic example. This is a very common idiomatic `LiveData` approach to scenarios where the user makes new queries to the database. If you have been learning theoretical `LiveData` from short blogs and tutorials, I suggest you to examine some more real application level `LiveData` and MVVM usages like this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp) from Google. Start by learning how `TasksFragment` and `TasksViewModel` interact each other.

Comment: Okay, I moved code out. Got the insert to work inside the Alert Dialog.  Now I need to be able to retrieve a Synonym row from the db in order to get Id  so I can make final insert into the WordSynonymJoin.  Of course, we get a LiveData<List<Synonym>> object and I cannot get the Synonym out of it...  Thump... Thump... Thump... (head against keyboard...)  Do I have to somehow use the observe in the onCreate to get the Synonym object? Or am I still missing something... Thump... Thump... Thump...  Reading a lot of articles, but not a lot go as far as to use Room, just primitive types...

Comment: Always observe in `onCreate`. But I understand your struggle. `LiveData` is not a great solution when you need to implement a complex data flow. I suggest you to look into these possible refactor: (1) Use `DialogFragment` instead of using `AlertDialog`. `DialogFragment` can have its own `onCreate` and `ViewModel` so you can less complicated code in `Activity`. (2) Use `RxJava` instead of `LiveData`. `RxJava` has superior operators and much better at handling complex data flow. `RxJava` can be directly integrated with `Room` or `retrofit`.

Comment: (3) When I am forced to use `LiveData` instead of `RxJava`, I only use it to bridge between View and ViewModel layer. Other layers, ViewModel, Repository, Room, Networks are connected with callbacks. Also notice that most of the blogs, articles, and tutorials about AsyncTask are usually 5 or more years old. I believe `Executors` are the most popular solution that is being used for asynchronous works these days.

Comment: Cool, more to study. ;)  I really appreciate your time helping me on my way.  I have found more insight since asking this question; just not enough to get the project I am working on completed... yet!

Comment: Can you look at another question that I asked?  I would really like to hear your solution for this.  [question]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484288/how-to-retrieve-list-of-objects-from-dao-via-livedata-in-view-model-when-there?noredirect=1#comment101442426_57484288

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 wordSynonymJoinViewModel.getSynonymsByNotWord(wordId).observe(SynonymActivity.this, new Observer<List<SynonymWithWords>>() {
```

you are monitoring for synonyms, but inside of the observing, you show a dialog and allow more synonyms to be added. Everytime a new synonym is added, it creates a new AlertDialog.

So this is why you have to press cancel on each dialog.

To fix that, you can assign your AlertDialog to a field and use the `isShowing()` method to decide if you want to show another dialog (i.e. don't show another one if one is already showing.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing()

---

As for all your other questions, I'm sorry it's a bit too much for me to unpack.

I can share my thoughts on how I would do this though:

> I want to assign existing synonyms to a word in the dictionary.

Perhaps forget the database to start with and create an in memory solution.
Then later you can change this to be persisted.

In memory the structure looks like a Hashtable of Dictionary words and Synonym lookups `Map<String, List<String>>`.

This Map would be in a class called `Repository` that exposes someway for you to observe and update it (RxJava Observable) or LiveData like you have already.

Your Fragment would observe this Map displaying it in a RecyclerView using MVVM or MVP whatever you want.

You have a clicklistener on each row of the RecyclerView to add a new synonym. On click opens the dialog (or a new activity/fragment). After the user types the synonym you will save this through the repository to your Map - and therefore the original observer will update the RecyclerView.

You should not get in a loop state of opening multiple dialogs :/

Hope that helps, tbh it sounds like you are on the right track and just need to work at it a bit more.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  It gives me a direction to study in.  However, I have one nagging question.  Do we have to use LiveData<> or "does every query need to be observable?" every time we want to retrieve some information?  If not, what is the alternative?  I have tried to use an AsyncTask in the Repository to return a List of Synonyms but since they are asynchronous, the values seem to rarely be available by the time the methods returns and I get nulls instead.  Any thoughts or alternative ways to do this? or is LiveData<> "THE WAY" of doing things now?

Comment: You don't have to use LiveData, you could do something as simple as this with a Listener when learning: https://gist.github.com/blundell/902d7283489a5eb2edda7823d4a38b05 . RxJava has a big learning curve but it does get rid of the headache of threading. ASyncTask is fine as well, and can also use a Listener like in the gist I sent you.