# how to retrieve list of objects from dao via LiveData<> in View Model when there is no change to trigger onChange method in View Model in android

Tags: android, android-studio, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I am using android studios to build a dictionary app.  Everything has went fairly well with help from the SO community and now I have another question.

I have setup several custom dictionaries so that the user can store and view words in different dictionaries. (e.g. literature, programming, general, etc.)

These will be a FK id in the word entity and filled when the user adds new words.

In the MainActivity, I have an Options menu item for 'Change Dictionary'.  This brings up an AlertDialog where the user can change the dictionary and theoretically see a new set of words.

Here is the problem.  No changes to the database are happening when the user selects a particular dictionary so the onChange attached to the WordViewModel's getWordsByDictionaryId() method does not trigger. Hence, the LiveData> will not refill.

Code in onCreate() method:

```
    // get all words from WordDao
    mWordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this).get(WordViewModel.class);
    mWordViewModel.getWordByDictionaryId(dictionaryId).observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Word> words) {
            mainAdapter.setWords(words);
            mAllWords = words;
            mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Code in OnOptionsItemSelected() method:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder changeDictionaryDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        changeDictionaryDialog.setTitle("Select Dictionary:");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_spinner_view, null);

        mDictionaryStringList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDictionaryStringList = convertToList(mDictionaryList);

        final Spinner dictionarySpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.alert_dialog_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mDictionaryStringList);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dictionarySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        dictionarySpinner.setSelection(0);

        changeDictionaryDialog.setView(view);
        changeDictionaryDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final String dictionaryValue = dictionarySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                for (Dictionary dictionary : mDictionaryList) {
                    if (dictionary.getDictionaryName().trim().equals(dictionaryValue)) {
                        dictionaryId = dictionary.getDid();
                       LiveData<List<Word>> myNewList = mWordViewModel.getWordByDictionaryId(dictionaryId);
                        List<Word> testList = myNewList.
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        changeDictionaryDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        changeDictionaryDialog.create();
        changeDictionaryDialog.show();
```

Code in the WordViewModel:

```
public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordByDictionaryId(long dictionaryId) {
    return mWordRepository.getWordByDictionaryId(dictionaryId);
}
```

Code in WordDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE dictionary_id =:dictionaryId")
public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordsByDictionaryID(long dictionaryId);
```

Finally, the Word entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table",
indices = { @Index(value = "word", unique = true),
@Index("dictionary_id") })
public class Word {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long id;
private String word;
@ColumnInfo(name = "dictionary_id")
private long dictionaryId;

@Ignore
public Word(String word, long dictionaryId) {
    this.word = word;
    this.dictionaryId = dictionaryId;
}

public Word(long id, String word, long dictionaryId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.word = word;
    this.dictionaryId = dictionaryId;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public long getDictionaryId() {
    return dictionaryId;
}

public void setDictionaryId(long dictionaryId) {
    this.dictionaryId = dictionaryId;
}
}
```

I have tried to setup a background thread (AsyncTask), but the one time that I did, the results came after I needed them so the return value was null. Some SO developers have said don't use Asynctask, but I think the issue would still be timing...

I have also read a little about generating a callback.  Would that actually work in this situation?  It seems to me like it might put me in the same boat as the background thread.

I have been really struggling trying to learn how to get data out of this "wonderfully simple way to create databases" when it comes to getting data out of the SQLite database via Room persistence via View Model via LiveData via ???whatever comes next???. Is there a "Google" way to do this?  Or is this where the RxJava and other libraries come into play?

So my question is just this "exactly how can I get a List of entity objects out of the database if there is no onChange event through live data?"  Is there a best practices or right way to call the query without the LiveData wrapper?  or a way to access the query directly within the LiveData wrapper without needing the data to change to get things done?

Comment: when you pass a new dictionaryId, it constructs a new Query with that parameter and your observer is listening to only *that* query, so when your dictionary id changes, you will have to call the get function from viewmodel again to construct a new query and add observer to Livedata returned by that query

Comment: What you want to do is change the query parameter after constructing the query, I checked the documentation and resources and there is no way to change the parameter once a query is constructed, so I'm afraid there is no other option

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying...  I understand just enough to do what I did, but comprehension of experience is not there yet.  Could you provide an example with the code I provided you as to how to call the get function from the viewmodel again?  Are you referring to the getWordByDictionaryId() method as the "get" method?  If so, when I call the GetWordByDictionaryId() method in the AlertDialog, i cannot see or access the data.  I assumed it was because it is "LiveData".

Comment: That is what I meant, when the user selects an option in dialog, you send tell the viewmodel or the activity to update dictionaryId, and then call GetWordByDictionaryId() with this new id that you got from AlertDialog

Comment: Okay, I am looking at the LiveData<List<Word>> myNewList object, and I cannot see the data within it.  It appears to have run, but how do I extract out the data?

Comment: Same as you did in your activity, add an observer, you will get updated data in `onChanged()` function. If this doesn't make sense, I must be misinterpreting your problem..

Comment: So, I add the observer in the AlertDialog section of the code, like i did in the onCreate()?

Comment: Okay, that worked.  However, in another question that I wrote the other day.  Another developer advised me to only but the observer in the onCreate.  So, this is the only way for this scenario to work using LiveData and View Model observables?

Comment: I don't know the context so I can't say why he said it, but if you see my comment above, I advised you to call the observer again from Activity not the Dialog, the reason is that using LiveData with Fragments can cause some problems if the fragment is not destroyed. Instead, just send a message to your Activity or viewmodel from your dialog, and then add the observer from your activity.
Another important thing to note is that make sure to remove observers from your previous livedata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LiveData solution**

@Zohaib Amir's comment is correct. You can call `LiveData#observe()` on anywhere you want as long as you remember to clear the observers. One drawback with this approach is that you have to keep the reference to these observers and `LiveData` already has `Transformations.switchMap()` so that you can avoid that.

**ViewModel**

```
// Instance variable that stores the current dictionaryId that user wants to see.
private final MutableLiveData<Long> currentDictionaryId = new MutableLiveData<>();

// Instance variable that stores the current list of words. This will automatically change when currentDictionaryId value changes.
private final LiveData<List<Word>> words = Transformations.switchMap(currentDictionaryId, dictionaryId -> 
    mWordRepository.getWordByDictionaryId(dictionaryId));



// Set new dictionaryId
public void setDictionaryId(long dictionaryId) {
    currentDictionaryId.postValue(dictionaryId);
}

// Get LiveData to listen to
public LiveData<List<Word>> getWords() {
    return words;
}
```

**Activity**

```
// onCreate()
    // get all words from WordDao
    mWordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this).get(WordViewModel.class);
    mWordViewModel.setDictionaryId(dictionaryId);
    mWordViewModel.getWords().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Word> words) {
            mainAdapter.setWords(words);
            mAllWords = words;
            mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    // note that the order of calling setDictionaryId and getWords doesn't matter. setDictionaryId is supposed to call at anytime.
```

```
// OnOptionsItemSelected
    ...
    changeDictionaryDialog.setView(view);
        changeDictionaryDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final String dictionaryValue = dictionarySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                for (Dictionary dictionary : mDictionaryList) {
                    if (dictionary.getDictionaryName().trim().equals(dictionaryValue)) {
                        dictionaryId = dictionary.getDid();
                        mWordViewModel.setDictionaryId(dictionaryId);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    ...
```

This time I prepared other solutions so that you can compare. Other solutions (almost) do the exact same thing.

---

**Non-reactive solution**

You can implement above feature based on callbacks, and this means that you have to manually handle lifecycle changes, notifications, and threading. Also, there is a functional difference that `LiveData` will automatically notify the observer when there is a change in the db, while this callback design is just one-time look up only.

In this example, we will use `Executor` to execute tasks in the background thread.

**WordDao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE dictionary_id =:dictionaryId")
public List<Word> getWordsByDictionaryID(long dictionaryId); // notice that livedata is gone.
```

**WordRepository**
Database access must be done in a background thread. So when we access db, we need to switch to a background thread at some point. In this example, we will switch to the background
thread in this layer.

```
// This executor is needed to run Runnables on a background thread. In real application, you may
// create this executor outside of this repository and later inject it to this repository.
private final Executor ioExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();


private void getWordByDictionaryId(long dictionaryId, Consumer<List<Word>> callback) {
    ioExecutor.execute(() -> {
        List<Word> wordList = wordDao.getWordsByDictionaryId(dictionaryId);
        callback.accept(wordList);
    });
}
```

**WordViewModel**
There isn't much ViewModel does in this example. Just pass the parameters to the repository.

```
public void getWordByDictionaryId(long dictionaryId, Consumer<List<Word>> callback) {
    mWordRepository.getWordByDictionaryId(dictionaryId, callback);
}
```

**Activity**
Note that `Consumer#accept` will run on a background thread. Therefore before you do anything with the ui, you need to switch back to the ui thread.

```
// onCreate
mWordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this).get(WordViewModel.class);
mWordViewModel.getWordByDictionaryId(dictionaryId, words -> {
    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        if (isFinishing() || isDestroyed()) return; // if the activity is finishing, don't do anything.

        mainAdapter.setWords(words);
        mAllWords = words;
        mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
});


// onOptionsItemSelected
changeDictionaryDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        final String dictionaryValue = dictionarySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        for (Dictionary dictionary : mDictionaryList) {
            if (dictionary.getDictionaryName().trim().equals(dictionaryValue)) {
                dictionaryId = dictionary.getDid();
                mWordViewModel.getWordByDictionaryId(dictionaryId, words -> {
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        if (isFinishing() || isDestroyed()) return; // if the activity is finishing, don't do anything.

                        mainAdapter.setWords(words);
                        mAllWords = words;
                        mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    });
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

**RxJava**

`RxJava` solution will look much like the `LiveData` solution. It has many advantages over `LiveData`: it has lots of observables and operators to work with. These advantages are more apparent in more complex applications, where you need to do conditional or delayed async tasks, periodic tasks, multiple requests chained one after the other, error handlings, etc.

**WordDao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE dictionary_id =:dictionaryId")
public Flowable<List<Word>> getWordsByDictionaryID(long dictionaryId);
```

**ViewModel**

```
private final BehaviorProcessor<Long> currentDictionaryId = BehaviorProcessor.create();

// Set new dictionaryId
public void setDictionaryId(long dictionaryId) {
    currentDictionaryId.onNext(dictionaryId);
}

// Get Flowable to listen to
public Flowable<List<Word>> getWords() {
    return currentDictionaryId.switchMap(dictionaryId -> mWordRepository
        .getWordByDictionaryId(dictionaryId)
        // add ".take(1)" if you need one-time look up.
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())); 
}
```

**Activity**

```
private fianl CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

// onCreate()
mWordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this).get(WordViewModel.class);
mWordViewModel.setDictionaryId(dictionaryId);
disposables.add(mWordViewModel.getWords()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
    .subscribe(words -> {
        mainAdapter.setWords(words);
        mAllWords = words;
        mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });


// onOptionsItemSelected()
 changeDictionaryDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        final String dictionaryValue = dictionarySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        for (Dictionary dictionary : mDictionaryList) {
            if (dictionary.getDictionaryName().trim().equals(dictionaryValue)) {
                dictionaryId = dictionary.getDid();
                mWordViewModel.setDictionaryId(dictionaryId);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});

// onDestroy()
disposables.clear();
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience and willingness to help me learn.  This has been what I have been trying to find in all of the documents that I have read so far. Many of the documents that i have read have stopped just short of this answer and would not have gone to such depth.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Just tried the first example above and it did exactly what I wanted it to do.  It returned a subset of data from the Word table based on the user input for the specific dictionary they requested.

Comment: so, going with the LiveData<> method, anytime that I want to get information from a LiveData<> wrapped query, do I need to use the above code to force a "change" when there is not actually a change happening? Or is there another way? I have run into different circumstances where I want to get a List<Word> or just a Word from a DAO query and I just can't quite seem to come to a solution, but in the back of my mind, i seem to be gravitating in that direction. Is that a valid solution to gravitate towards? Or is there another way of calling the query directly?

Comment: @MSMartens, you should not need to force anything. You should be able to call `.getValue()` to peek on `LiveData`, if the `LiveData` is holding any value in it and there is no change.

Comment: But, if I want to get a value from a Query that accepts a WHERE, then I use the code you mentioned above. Correct?  Like we were talking about with the dictionary id changing?  Say I wanted to get a different word using a word_id, then I would add the code in the ViewModel that would use the Transformations.SwitchMap() correct?  Just trying to see if my current understanding is correct...  Thanks

Comment: Does not really matter whether the query is conditional or not. If you are querying just one time, you should just `.observe` that query. If the query needs to dynamically react to some other value, like in the example above, you should use `Transfermations.SwitchMap()`. If you just want to peek on a `LiveData` value that is already loaded, use `LiveData#getValue`.

Comment: Let's say you are building a Weather app, and want to fetch the weather data of current city, then you wouldn't need to use `switchMap` because the parameter--current city--is fixed, even if the query has conditional parameters.